# Force override of DynamoDB table name

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, amazon-dynamodb, prototypal-inheritance

I would like to create a general DynamoDB schema, which shall be shared by a number of DynamoDb table classes:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "please_dont_create_me!")
public abstract class Schema {
  @DynamoDBHashKey
  private String id;

  private String value;

  /* setters and getters .. */
}


@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "table_1")
public class FirstTable extends Schema {
}


// Woops, I forgot to annotate with @DynamoDBTable
public class SecondTable extends Schema {

}
```

Saving an instance of `FirstTable` works as expected:

```
FirstTable ft = new FirstTable();
ft.setId("occupation");
ft.setValue("artist");
mapper.save(ft);  // Saves (occupation, artist) to 'table_1'
```

Now saving `SecondTable`, which I forgot to annotate with `@DynamoDBTable`:

```
SecondTable st = new SecondTable();
st.setId("hobby");
st.setValue("drawing");
mapper.save(st);  // Saves (hobby, drawing) to 'please_dont_create_me!'
```

Is it possible to create `Schema` in such a way so as to avoid this situation?

My thoughts:

- `Schema` must be annotated with `@DynamoDBTable`, otherwise the fields it defines are not picked up (when attempting to save FirstTable, an exception is thrown about a missing hashKey, for example)
- tableName is mandatory and non-null. I can set it to an invalid table name (e.g. using special characters in the name) but.. that is a very hacky solution
- Having `Schema` as an interface instead would not really work*. The main flaw is that `@DynamoDBHashKey` and other field annotations are not inherited.

*I have not actually tried using an interface

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect when saving SecondTable with no @DynamoDBTable annotation?

If the goal is to play with the table name I suggest you dive into [TableNameResolver](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameResolver.html).

Answer (score 1):

You want to make your table selection dynamic with same pojo class. This is how I did.

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
client.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8000/");
String tableName="User";
User user = new User(); 
user.setName("Ohelig");
TableNameOverride config = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride(tableName);
mapper.save(user, new DynamoDBMapperConfig(config));
```